# Flutter Doctor Error: pub did not create .dart_tools/package_config.json file

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to install Flutter on my Windows 11 machine. It was already installed but for some reason I just felt like installing it again "to be sure" so I followed the Flutter documentation to install it. When I first ran `flutter doctor` I got this:

```
Found an existing Pub cache at C:\Users\900834\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache.
It can be repaired by running `dart pub cache repair`.
It can be reset by running `dart pub cache clean`.
LocalDirectory: 'C:\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools': pub did not create
.dart_tools/package_config.json file.
```

And now I am getting this every time so I can't do anything:
`LocalDirectory: 'C:\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools': pub did not create .dart_tools/package_config.json file.`

I tried running dart pub cache repair and dart pub cache clean as suggested in the error message, but the issue persists. I also tried creating a new Flutter project using flutter create <project_name> but encountered the same error. I have tried reinstalling the Flutter SDK with the latest stable version, restarting the computer, deleting the Pub file, etc. but everything I tried had he same results.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. i dont know the exact technicalities but what i did was deleting flutter and start from scratch again. I dont have any problems using flutter now. you can follow this link: https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows

Comment: Thanks but I already tried reinstalling it. I tried deleting the flutter folder and also the Pub folder, then installing it again. Unfortunately it doesn't work :(

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).